# How to politely ask the OP for feedback about your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes you answer a question, and the OP doesn't accept or upvote it, but also doesn't downvote, or provide a comment as to why it doesn't help them. So then you're left wondering whether they used the answer and moved on, or they couldn't use the answer in their specific situation, or maybe you misinterpreted the question, or the answer was simply not correct.

In this situation, I'm often tempted to ask the OP for feedback in a comment, but I'm wondering whether this is frowned upon as being too pushy. Is there an etiquette for this situation?

(Feedback wouldn't just satisfy my curiosity and make me feel better about putting in effort to answer questions, it could help me improve the answer, and help other users gauge the quality of the answer.)

Comment: i usually just move on and do nothing. For all I know the op may have left for vacation, or solved it on their own and never looked back. but... i doubt  it would be "frowned upon" to request feedback, i just don't think it'd be very fruitful either.

Comment: Worthwhile remembering that the OP is not the only user. Just because the OP didn't respond doesn't mean it wasn't useful to *someone*.

Comment: if they have feedback, they can post it.  If they don't have any feedback, then they don't have any feedback.  There's no reason for you to do anything.

Comment: @Louis It is sort of a duplicate, but i'm not specifically talking about new low-rep users. I've come to accept that those will likely never come back to respond.

Comment: @m69 the answer in that dupe is still appropriate to this answer, imo. And the question is similar enough. Low or high rep users, it's still the same. You can politely ask for feedback such as, "Does this answer your question?" or "Let me know if you need more explanation". Just don't be pushy and if they don't respond, move on

Comment: @codeMagic Fair enough; I marked it as answered.