# What to do if a questioner doesn't provide feedback for his question?

Tags: discussion, support

I tried to find the answer in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and could not find the answer I was seeking, but I think this question is an important one.

Let's suppose a user ask a question, [by example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808141/finding-pairs-of-numbers-in-substring-with-regex/), a few people propose answers (which seem to me good answers for the problem). More than one week later, the user still hasn't done any follow-up at all.

Yesterday, I even posted a comment suggesting to ask for clarifications if the given answers were not clear enough, still no feedback...

I don't mind offering some of my free time and expertise to help other developers, but I consider it as minimal respect to ensuring the follow-up of the answers/comments when asking a question.

I think we should emphasize the importance for a user to provide proper feedback on his questions in the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

My question is the following : **What should I do, as an active member of the community, if I consider that a user is not putting enough effort to let us know if his answer was solved or not?**

Comment: You can't *make* someone do the work or miraculously become active. My advice would be to try contacting them. If all fails, then move on. After all, it's there fault for not paying attention to given help.

Comment: The people participating in the communities have a job, friends and family to attend too. A user cannot simply take our personal time for granted.  In my honest opinion, we should be able to tag such a questions and penalize user that recurrently not doing proper feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with "ask-and-run" questioners](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256788/dealing-with-ask-and-run-questioners) and [How to politely ask the OP for feedback about your answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311963/how-to-politely-ask-the-op-for-feedback-about-your-answer)

Comment: But it's not their obligation to get to you. Sure, you are spending your time to help, but what's the point of penalization? It'll most likely discourage them even more and turn them away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What should I do, as an active member of the community, if I consider that a user is not putting enough effort to let us know if his answer was solved or not?

Nothing. I know, that's not the answer you were looking for, but it is nevertheless the *correct* answer.

Here are two reasons:

1. Practically speaking, there is nothing that you or anyone else possibly *could* do. We can't reach out over the Internet and coerce people into behaving a certain way. The person might be dead, in a coma, or incarcerated. Or they might have won the lottery and no longer care about programming. Or they might just be too busy to come back to the question right now because of having a "life" or something (I keep hearing about those). So rather than worrying about impossible problems, we just don't.
2. This website has a broader purpose than answering one person's question. Our *principal* goal is to build up a repository of quality answers to practical programming questions. Now, in order to do that, we need people to ask questions, and the way we incentivize them to do that is by providing a community of experts who will actually answer their questions. And, too, many answerers are here because they find pleasure in helping others to solve their problems. There is nothing wrong with that. But we are not simply a help desk. There is a purpose to Q&A outside of the person who originally asked the question. Uncountable numbers of people navigate to this web site via Google <strike>and other popular search engines</strike> and benefit from answers. If you can't help the person who originally asked the question, then at least you are helping these other people. And there are a whole lot more of them, so by a strictly utilitarian standard, you're doing a lot more good.

So, all you can do is leave a comment asking for clarification, and the asker will be automatically notified of your comment. If they respond, great. If not, there's nothing more that you can do.

If their lack of response means that the question is unclear, insufficiently detailed, or otherwise unanswerable, then the question should be (A) downvoted and (B) closed. Downvotes indicate that the question is problematic and should not be appearing on the radar of other experts. Closure definitively marks the question as having a content problem, and is the first step to deletion. Deletion is, of course, not inevitable: if the person does eventually come back and update their question, it can be re-opened. If someone else has a similar problem and can whip the question into shape, that's fine too. But if none of that ever happens, then we will ultimately remove the broken window.

> I think we should emphasize the importance for a user to provide proper feedback on his questions in the how to ask page.

[I disagree.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page#comment361445_326882) This has been suggested before, and it seems like a good idea at first blush, but what we should *really* be doing is trying to solve the problem at its core. The core problem is that the question is incomplete and does not contain enough details. These details should have been included from the outset so that no one has to waste their time posting comments and waiting for a response. [We should therefore be encouraging users to include all relevant information in their questions from the outset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page), rather than encouraging them to follow the *contingency* plan of using comments to clarify.

> In my honest opinion, we should be able to tag such a questions and penalize user that recurrently not doing proper feedback.

Agreed. In fact, you can. By (A) [downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), and (B) voting to close. Since you do not yet have close vote privileges ([based on reputation score; requires 3k+](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)), you have to [*flag* the question as "should be closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: To your last paragraph, that is the response to a poorly asked question, not the response to an author who is not providing feedback on the quality of answers.  You don't downvote or vote to close a great question just because the author isn't providing feedback on the quality of the answers.

Comment: @Servy Well personally, downvote would be my first reflex as I consider that a questioner is responsible for managing his question during the whole process (even if it is a good one). Still, I don't like downvoting since it does not indicate to the user the reason you don't like the question. A special (community invisible) marker for signaling that the questioner did not do proper follow up seem enough. IMO, the negative actions should be taken only if the problem is recurring.

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque Users are not expected nor responsible for providing feedback on the quality of the answers posted.  They are *allowed* to provide that feedback, but they are not *required* to do so.  They may well not even have feedback to provide.  It is the community that is primarily responsible for judging answers.  The question author is responsible for asking a good question, that's all.

Comment: @Servy You think like a user with a lot reputation. Now that all the candy questions have been asked and answered, it is way harder for junior developers to ask good questions and provide the good answer for those questions than it initially was. We, the juniors, too have the right to be recognized for our answers!

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque So you're just upset that you're not getting as many Imaginary Internet Points as you want, and are unconcerned about the quality of the content, or how helpful the site is as a resource.  That's rather unfortunate.  If you only care about getting points, and not actually being helpful, then by all means, none of my arguments are relevant to you.

Comment: @Servy There's no shame for me to want to build an online C.V. I can use afterward to get in touch with good employers. Everyone need a carrot somewhere being either money (for work) or community points (for online an online C.V.). Not everyone comes from a wealthy family and some of us have to get debts and work hard to build themselves a career.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is unclear to the point that you can't determine what the correct answer should be, then *you shouldn't be answering the question in the first place*, you should be voting to close it.  If the author never improves the question to the point that it becomes answerable, it will most likely end up being deleted eventually.

If the question is clear and answerable, and the author simply never indicates that they like a given answer, then there is nothing that needs to be done.  If there's a good question with a good answer that the community has determined to be of high quality, then there is no need at all for the author to provide their feedback.

Comment: I respect your opinion, but I still consider that feedback is important and represent minimal respect for other users.

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque Consider that in most cases the OP's feedback is *worth much less* than other user's feedback.  They are quite often least capable of evaluating the quality of the answers of the people participating in the question.  Furthermore, The author providing their feedback is in no way important to the actual goals of the site, namely providing quality answers to quality questions.  It might personally make you feel good, but that doesn't make it important for the question to achieve its goals.